# http_code = 0 Help Me Please

Tags: php, api

Here I am on a project to make a small site to retrieve data from an API by making requests in PHP

I have already designed this kind of site with requests, but in JS.

To do well, I would like to use a REST client: https://github.com/tcdent/php-restclient which I managed to install.

I have already written a code start in the php file:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit',(ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let saisi = document.getElementById('sic').value;
    console.log(saisi);
    if(isNaN(saisi) || saisi.length != 14){
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Veuillez rentrer un numéro SIRET valable (14 chiffres)";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Voici le résultat";
    }
})
```

```html
<?php 
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Enterprise</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="sic"> Numéro de SIRET : </label>
            <input type="text" id="sic" name="texte"/>
            <input type="submit" value="envoyer" id="valider"/>
        </form>
        <p id="result"></p>
        
        <?php
            $api = new RestClient([
                'base_url' => "https://entreprise.data.gouv.fr/api/sirene/v3/", 
                'format' => "json",
            ]);
                
            $result = $api->get("etablissements/48852291300026");
                var_dump($result);
            if($result->info->http_code == 200)
                var_dump($result->decode_response());
            if($result->info->http_code == 404)
                echo 'Non trouvé';
            if($result->info->http_code == 429)
                echo 'Seuil de requête dépassé';
            if($result->info->http_code == 500)
                echo 'Serveur HS';
        ?>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But in the browser it doesn't show me what I want because I have this http_code  :

public 'http_code' => int 0

I would like to point out that I obviously tried the url (https:// entreprise.data.gouv.fr/api/sirene/v3/etablissements/48852291300026) directly in the browser as well as in Postman in get. Both show me the JSON array of the result.
I work with WAMP
My php is version 7.4.0 and Composer is version 1.10.6

I did the test on another computer at home and therefore with the same internet box, I have the same result.

My other site with API requests in JS works fine ...

I don't see where the concern would come from... Thanks for your help

Comment: If your API have a swagger, check headers, maybe you need some. Before coding, check your API call with Postman or curl.
And little advice: use guzzle insteed this library.

Comment: Another clarification, a friend tested my code at home and it works perfectly. Moreover I tried with other API, I have the same concern.

For example, the site that I developed with an API request in Javascript works fine, but when I use this same API in this code in PHP version, it doesn't work anymore ... I don't think the problem comes from API